# Half way to replicate the Amazon search box. How to show and assign a value of the selected category?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap I am trying to replicate the amazon search box that you select a category and hit it.
The problem is that I do not know how to have the functionality. What I mean is if I choose an option from the dropdown list, it should replace the current option. And secondly, when I hit the search button to post an identified value of that category.

Here is the live version: 
To summarize: When I choose the category "Another action" it should replace the current "Action". 
But also the "Another Action" should have a value of "2" to help me in the processing.

http://www.bootply.com/tkGKT9NULl

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a> </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Please don't link to live code. That isn't how this site works. Your question needs to contain everything required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: yes and this is what i did, didn't I? i dont believe however that it is a reason for downvote

Comment: explanation of wanted behavior is confusing... not sure at all what your goal is. There doesn't seem to be any javascript in the demo either

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a shot in the dark, but this is the jQuery (since jQuery is one of the listed tags) to see the active Action and change the active action on click.  In the function selectSearchAction the variable i is your list index, which for Another Action would be 1 (index starts from 0) which you could use for processing however you'd like.

Bootply fork: http://www.bootply.com/QjyUPtaw35

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var actionList = $('#searchAction').find('li');

    actionList.on('click', 'a', function(e){
        var i = $(this).parent().index();
        selectSearchAction(i);
    });

    function selectSearchAction(i){
        var actionItem = actionList.eq(i);
        action = actionItem.find('a').text();
        actionList.removeClass('active');
        actionItem.addClass('active');
        $('#selectedAction').html(action);
        $('#actionInput').val(action);
    }

});
```

I changed your markup a little to include some additional IDs to make finding the relevant elements.  I also added a span around the action in your button.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="actionButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span id="selectedAction">Action </span><span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul id="searchAction" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <input id="actionInput" type="hidden" value=""> 
       <span class="input-group-addon"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a> </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your help. I implemented it, however I can not find how to include IDs in the different options when I submit the form. Can you clarify that please?

Comment: I mean I can not find a way to post parameters

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos I've edited my solution to include a new bootply link and an input element to contain the selected action.

Answer (score -1):

ok from your question it was hard to decipher, but if I understood you right, all that you need to do is  add code to handle the button text change, I have posted my solution live as the example you quoted uses bootstrap

http://www.bootply.com/tkGKT9NULl#

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

  $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');

});
```

This way when the dropdown is clicked the button text can be changed, if you want to set another value you can add code below that first line.